# Django REST API browser page not showing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Model` with some `Serializers` as well as a `ModelViewSet` which handle the back-end. Usually when I go to the API endpoint in the browser it will show the Dajgno REST (Red and Gray) browasble API page:

e.g. `localhost:8000/api/some-api` should show the REST framework page but returns the queryset in JSON instead.

Right now when I go there I am being returned a JSON queryset, or if an error occurs it shows it in plain text (not even the Django error page). Maybe I deleted something somewhere?

```
class PoliciesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Policies and Procedures API endpoint.
    """
    serializer_class = PoliciesSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = PoliciesAndProcedures.objects.all()
        queryset = qs.filter(
            receiver=self.request.user.role
        ) | qs.filter(
            sender=self.request.user
        )
        return queryset.distinct()
```

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/policies', PoliciesViewSet, basename='policies-api')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

When I visit `http://test2.localhost:8000/api/policies/` it shows:

> [{"id":5,"category":{"id":3,"parent":{"id":1,"title":"Cat 1","parent":null,"groups":[6]},"title":"Subcat 1 - 1","groups":[1,2,3,4,6,7]},"title":"wefqwefq","contents":....

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment [**`DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers) in your **settings.py**.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'authentication.authenticate.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
    #     'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    # ),
}
```

Comment: Saaaweeeeeeet! Thanks! I will hit the docs for more on the Renderers! I read up on them but didn't see this issue addressed.

Comment: I think I know what happened... I must have followed default some instructions online for the setup of REST and the renderer classes were part of it.